# How to draw rectangle around object using features (ORB)

Tags: opencv, tracking, orb

Hello all :) I'm just beginner of openCV.

I've been trying to develop tracking program using **ORB**.
I just want to draw rectangle around detected object.

This is part of the
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8sU5.jpg) of tracking program. 'Black car' is what I want to track (interested object). As you can see, there are lots of unnecessary features and detected features around 'Black car'.

For drawing around detected object, I thought there are 2 ways.

1) Find density of features : As you can see, features around 'Black car' is more dense than others. So...If I can calculate how dense they are, (probably the area around 'Black car' has the highest density..?) then I can draw rectangle more easily.

2) Remove unnecessary features : If only necessary features is left, I can calculate center of them.

From now on, I've been using 'center of all features'. But it is not effective than I thought. Because rectangle was drawn little bit far away from 'Black car' when I used this way.

If there are functions or algorithms related to above 2 ways, please let me know! If you guys know better way then above things, it also really helpful to me.

Thank you in advance and hope you guys have great day :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to keypoints you could do the following:

1. detect and describe all keypoints in both images
2. compute the matching of keypoints
3. compute the best RANSAC homography
4. choose all inlier to be one object which might be the background
5. from all non-inlier keypoints compute the next best RANSAC homography
6. choose all inlier to be another object
7. ... and so on
8. until too few keypoints left or no good homography can be computed.

Instead or in addition you can use many other methods (background subtraction, probabilistic tracking, size assumptions, and so on). All in all it is not a trivial task if you expect good results.

Comment: I don't see how that answers the question. He didn't mention matching feature between two images. He's talking about "black car" as in detecting anything that resembles black cars. I don't think he has any training data or anything to work as a ground truth he is trying to match test data to.

Comment: still this answers the question. You can still match keypoints between two images. Basically think about image mosaicing with an option to filter out moving objects (which would be visible twice in the panorama) but instead of removing those objects just extract them because they're the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

First to answer your question - to use features to detect an object you need to know what are you're trying to match them to or be sure that the object will always present much more features than the background. None of these is the case in your situation.

Using features on their own for deciding where the cars is will prove to be very unreliable when you start using real data since the background might prove to be noisy and contain more corners than the car itself.

First of all: gather real data as soon as you can. There is no point in developing algorithms with a fake image like you provided, especially since you don't have experience with OpenCV and can't foresee future problems.

Second of all: developing for videos is a bit different than developing for still images. Check out [this tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/), as it may prove to be quite useful for your situation.

The most basic pipeline, for your problem would look something like this:

```
perform some preprocessing (blurring for example)
calculate difference between 2 consecutive frames, to obtain the moving objects; 
perform some filtering and binarization; 
find contours of the objects; 
decide if any of them is a car based on shape and size; 
find out it's color; 
draw a rectangle around it if it's black.
```

Of course there are more advanced techniques you could use for every step of this algorithm, but I would recommend to start with the simple approach.